# Update database record after 30 (month) day

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, cron

I have a submissions list and each one has its date_added, I am running also cron every day and checking if date_added is >= 30 day.

I am looking for a correct date check every day (cron) so if date_added is >= 30 day something must happen.

Date format: 2019-12-14 08:38:09

My code:

```
$afterMonth = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 months"));
```

Query Comparation:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('last_updated') . ' >= ' . $db->quote($afterMonth));
```

I was just testing <= and it is working well, but have no idea how to test >= or if it is working.

suggest me better code, please as I am not strong in php.

Comment: I'm not verse with joomla but if i'm reading your code correctly, it looks as if your query will always return 0 rows because your `$afterMonth` is set to the future and no submission list's `last_updated` will be greater than it. Therefore, is there a way to find the date difference between *now* and `$last_updated` as the query is performed and then base your selection on the necessary parameters on that date/time *difference*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the date logic in SQL, you won't need this line:

```
$afterMonth = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 months"));
```

Change your `where` clause:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('last_updated') . ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY');
```

We're using the `DATE_SUB()` SQL function to subtract a timespan from a given date. We use `CURDATE()` to get the current date and then `INTERVAL 30 DAY` to set the timespan to subtract.

You could also just use:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('last_updated') . ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');
```

More on this function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp)

Comment: but the syntax is not working, as ut us Joomla query maybe. so need to way to find

Comment: @Gocha you're correct, my answer was missing a closing `)` - please try the updated answer